# STRING_AGG with OVER() clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation, listagg, string-agg

Is there any equivalent of Postgres: `STRING_AGG` with `OVER()` or Oracle `LISTAGG` with `OVER()` in SQL Server? I would like to concatenate text values without grouping it, so I need `STRING_AGG` in analytical version, but according to docs is not [supported in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&preserve-view=true):

> The `OVER` clause may follow all aggregate functions, except the `STRING_AGG`, `GROUPING` or `GROUPING_ID` functions.

Do I need to create subquery in my `SELECT` or is there better approach for that?

Answer (score 0):

No, `STRING_AGG` is only implemented as an aggregate function (at time of writing) with support for the `WITHIN GROUP` clause, it cannot be windowed (using an `OVER` clause). You will need to use a subquery/CTE/derived table:

```sql
SELECT YT.YourID,
       YT.YourGroupingColumn,
       DT.AggregatedString
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT STRING_AGG(YourAggregatingColumn,',') AS AggregatedString
                  FROM dbo.YourTable sq
                  WHERE sq.YourGroupingColumn = YT.YourGroupingColumn) DT;

SELECT YT.YourID,
       YT.YourGroupingColumn,
       DT.AggregatedString
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT sq.YourGroupingColumn,
                       STRING_AGG(sq.YourAggregatingColumn,',') AS AggregatedString
                FROM dbo.YourTable sq
                GROUP BY sq.YourGroupingColumn) DT ON YT.YourGroupingColumn = DT.YourGroupingColumn;
WITH Agg AS(
     SELECT sq.YourGroupingColumn,
            STRING_AGG(sq.YourAggregatingColumn,',') AS AggregatedString
     FROM dbo.YourTable sq
     GROUP BY sq.YourGroupingColumn)
SELECT YT.YourID,
       YT.YourGroupingColumn,
       A.AggregatedString
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     LEFT JOIN Agg A ON YT.YourGroupingColumn = A.YourGroupingColumn;
```

With no sample data, I can't test what would be most performant for you; you will need to do that off your own back (I expect the CTE and Derived table to have very similar, if not identical, query plans though).